# Print the numbers and pick the right for loop

Tags: java

The question is: write a method that is passed an `int n` and returns a `String` that counts down from n to 1. Ex `countDown(3)` prints `321`

My code is:

```
public class CountDown {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int n = n; n> 0; n--;) {
            System.out.println("i=" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner at coding but I'm not sure how to fix this. I believe my for loop is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see that your requirements state that you need a method named `countDown()`. I suggest you look at a Java tutorial to learn how to write a method. To start, you can just create it with an empty body.

Comment: Nearly there. You want for(int i = n; i > 0; i--) { ...

Answer (score 2):

In your current attempt you haven't declared `n` variable and then re-declared it inside the `for` loop which is not allowed.

You should declare a new `countDown(int)` method and then use either `while` or `for` loop. It could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(countDown(3));
}

private static String countDown(int n) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  while (n > 0) {
    builder.append(n);
    n--;
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable you declared in your for loop (`n`) is different than the one you printed (`i`), and you are assigning `n` to `n` when it is declared. You need to do this in order to make it work:

- Either change the value of the variable in your for loop from `n` to `i` or print out `n` instead of `i`
- Change the declaration of the variable to not assign it to itself

Here is one way:

```
public class CountDown {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--;) {
            System.out.println("i=" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

This will be the output:

```
i=5
i=4
i=3
i=2
i=1
```